# Calculate a sequence of percentages using while loop in C

Tags: c

I need to calculate formulas for different percentages of the speed of light. The percentages are 30, 60, 90, 93, 96, 99, 99.3, 99.6, 99.9, 99.93, etc. all the way to 99.999%. 
I am trying to find a way to get that sequence using only loops and operators but couldn't come up with anything conclusive. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I doubt most of C programmers know the meaning of "proper" and "improper" times for percentages of the speed of light.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. You don't need to understand those concepts, he's just asking how to generate that numeric sequence. Increment a digit by 3 until it gets to 9, then repeat with the next digit.

Comment: Then these concepts should be removed from the question.

Comment: Use nested `for` loops. The outer loop specifies the multiplier of the increment, the inner loop goes from 0 to 3.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Come on, there's nothing wrong with including the motivation of the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Not when it is obfuscating the real problem up to a point "nah, I have no idea what he is talking about". Anyway, to the question. I have a strong feeling that it can be done with single loop and `log`....

Comment: I've edited it for the benefit of people who can't understand "I am trying to find a way to get that sequence" as being the gist of the question.

Comment: Check this out: https://ideone.com/HZuFX0 I came up with this, but have a little idea why it is working :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I suspect OP's "only loops and operators" is one on those limitations barring `pow()`.  Yet not to hard to code around.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just wanted to give a little context on why I needed those numbers. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> The percentages are 30, 60, 90, 93, 96, 99, 99.3, 99.6, 99.9, 99.93, etc. all the way to 99.999%

Use the difference from 1.0: .7, ... .07, ... .007, ..., a geometric progression.

Each `(1.0 - dif/power10) * 100.0` calculation does not depend on prior FP calculations that may introduce accumulated round-off error.<sup>1</sup>

```
int main(void) {
  double power10 = 1.0;
  for (int power = -1; power >= -5; power--) {
    power10 *= 10.0;
    for (int digit = 3; digit <= 9; digit += 3) {
      int dif = 10 - digit;
      printf("%g%%\n", (1.0 - dif/power10) * 100.0);
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
30%
60%
90%
93%
96%
99%
99.3%
99.6%
99.9%
99.93%
99.96%
99.99%
99.993%
99.996%
99.999%
```

<sup>1</sup> `power10 *= 10.0;` is certainly exact for maybe up to 10<sup>22</sup>.

---

For those who like [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com), a modest attempt that outputs like the above.

```
int main() {
for(int i=0;i<15;i++)printf("%g%%\n",100-atof((char[]){'7'-i%3*3,'0','e','-','0'+i/3,0}));
}
```

Comment: I really didn't think of doing anything like that thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve this is to write a loop that does `current += 30` three times, then `current += 3`, again three times, then `current += 0.3`, and so on.
The code could look as follows:

```
int main() {

    double current=0;
    double toAdd=30;
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            current+=toAdd;
            printf("%lf\n",current);
        }
        toAdd /= 10;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.